# What is this component? (range finder)

Tags: sensors

I've taken apart an [old range finder (see photo here)](https://plus.google.com/111652317143259686566/posts/75TraxED8bg). It uses a circular, seemingly gold-plated, two-wire sensor that I'd like to re-use in an Arduino project.
I'm looking for a datasheet of the sensor and/or a circuit-diagram. Any help is welcome.﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big circular parts likely is ultrasonic transducer as used in instant camera.

http://www.uoxray.uoregon.edu/polamod/

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=polaroid+ultrasonic+ranging+module&revid=399558007&safe=off

Working principle is same as modern unit, easily available at a few US dollars. The transducer does NOT work by itself, needs the associate PCB to work.

Comment: Thanks! This got me going. The first link provided shows pictures of the exact same component.